# Transform wrongly transformed data with .gsb file

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have data which originally came in GK coordinates (EPSG:31467) as an DXF. This data was transformed using the QGIS standard .gsb file for Germany and then got digitalized (basically draw the lines etc into a new layer and fill in attributes which are only visible in the DXF). Now I just came to realize that the transformation was done using the Germany-wide grid, but it actualy should have been transformed using the grid of the state Baden-Würtemberg (BWTA2017.gsb). How can I transform my data which I have already digitized based on the wrongly transformed DXF? Is there any posibility? There is a difference of ~5cm when I load the original DXF into QGIS and reproject it on the fly with the BWTA2017.gsb compared to the German-wide grid.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can improve the precision using the transformed data. As stated on the [AdV Website](http://www.adv-online.de/icc/extdeu/nav/9ae/9ae594bb-a094-311a-3b21-718a438ad1b2&sel_uCon=3c10e056-7955-311a-3b21-718a438ad1b2&uTem=73d607d6-b048-65f1-80fa-29f08a07b51a.htm), accuracy using BeTA2007 is within several centimetres or even decimetres. Perhaps, though, you can transform the data back to GK3 using BeTA2007 and then transform them again using BWTA2017. However, I am not sure if the coordinate transformation is easily and accurately reversible.

Comment: i tried un-transforming the data back into GK and then forth again into UTM using BWTA2017, unfortunately this did not work. i guess i have to put a lot of time into it, i figured the processing tool "snap geometries to layer" does help alot (snapping the wrongly transformed to a right transformed layer)